# Where is my Startup.cs file in my Blazor default directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-server-side, visual-studio-2022

I recently went through a Blazor Pluralsight course (dated 2020) that had a Server-side Blazor project that had a Startup.cs file along with a Program.cs file in the default directory.  I fired up Visual Studio 2022 and created my first Blazor Server-side project and all I have is a Program.cs file.  Why is that?  Where is the Startup.cs file?  The contents of the single Program.cs file look nothing like the contents of the Pluralsight project that had a Program.cs and and Startup.cs which makes setting up configuration a little confusing.  What's going on here?

Comment: All the templates were updated for .NET 6 to make use of the new Minimal APIs. Maybe following the latest [Blazor tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) might help re-orient yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In net6, the default sample added:" Unifies Startup.cs and Program.cs into a single Program.cs file.". According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-6.0?view=aspnetcore-6.0#minimal-apis